# Rotate and Tilt image horizontally and vertically using seekbar progress value

Tags: android, c++, image-processing, image-editing, ucrop

I am using UCROP library and able to rotate the image but not able to get code for tilt image horizontally and vertically, for tilt I used rotationY and rotationX on image but white spaces appears in container.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tygJq.png)